# How to use ST_SymDifference for polygons from the same table having the same name value in CARTO?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, carto, donut-polygons

I am very new to PostGIS2.4 and Postgresql 10 and having hard times to make holes inside a polygon using another polygon from a single table liveuamap by using `ST_SymDifference`.

[image: the polygon in the middle should be cleared]

The polygon in the middle should be cleared.

I searched a lot for an answer but nothing could serve in my situation for CARTO. I used the following query :

```
SELECT a.cartodb_id, b.cartodb_id,
    CAST (ST_AsText (ST_SymDifference (a.the_geom, b.the_geom) )
    AS VARCHAR(350) ) SYM_DIFF
  FROM liveuamap a, liveuamap b
  WHERE a.cartodb_id = 105 AND b.cartodb_id = 116
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] the question to provide the exact versions of PostgreSQL and PostGIS in use, and provide more information about the exact query you used.

Comment: I'm not sure what `ST_DymDifference` will do in this case - it's supposed to *find that portion of both polygons, that do not intersect*, which, in theory, could also work here - but you should definetely try `ST_Difference(<large_popy>, <small_poly>)' instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used `ST_SymDifference` but (correct me if I am wrong) you can achieve the same result with [`ST_Difference`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Difference.html). But before applying any of these functions, you should bear in mind that any SQL query inside BUILDER should select (a unique) `cartodb_id`, `the_geom` and `the_geom_webmercator`.

Check [this resource](https://github.com/GeoinquietosMadrid/intro-spatial-db/blob/master/exercises/carto.md#simple-clipping) to see how you can clip or create donnuts in CARTO. Again, notice that you will need to add `the_geom` to your query. So your query should be something like this:

```
WITH clip AS (
    SELECT
      1 as cartodb_id,
      a.cartodb_id as id_1,
      b.cartodb_id as id_2,
      ST_Difference(
        a.the_geom,
        b.the_geom
      ) as the_geom
    FROM
      table a,
      table b
    WHERE
      b.cartodb_id = {cartodb_id}
    AND
      a.cartodb_id = {cartodb_id})

SELECT 
    *, 
    ST_Transform(the_geom, 3857) as the_geom_webmercator
FROM
    clip
```